# How do I list all Versions in Redmine

Tags: redmine

I can do them per-project (select project, Settings, Versions), but not globally. How do I list all versions that exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to list all versions you need to do minimum one "shared" version. Hint: You can do it with "blocked" status.

Answer (score 0):

The page redmine/issues (assuming redmine is your server) shows all issues. You can show versions then sort on that column. It appears to sort versions by earliest due date followed by those with no version. You can also "group results by" and select versions.

However this isn't great if you have lots of bugs. And it doesn't show more information such as the due date of the version.